# Users without gravatar (avatar)?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, user-interface

In these days I see that there are many users without a gravatar (image) like this:

[image]

Addendum:

[image]

What is the reason?

Comment: This could be due to a host of things, and is often temporary. Does this problem still exist?

Comment: @Werner Very kind there are many user with this icon, actually. If you prefer I can add other images.

Comment: This seems to be site-wide; I've raised it on [meta.se]: [Gravatars not loaded for certain sources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356397/168244)

Comment: @Werner Thank you very much for your support and for the raised. There also other users without a gravatar.

Comment: It seems to be related to users logging in using their Google/Facebook account credentials, and then perhaps changing their profile images... Maybe. I don't know that much.

Comment: @Werner I have seen your answer and as usual I have voted +1 :-) Thank you very much.....for your constant cooperation.

Comment: I've seen it in blogs as well these days... so I don't think it's a SX thing.

Comment: @Rmano Hi, dear Rmano, excuse for my delay but these days are hard for me for school and for personal reasons including my health. Thank you for your comment that I appreciate and always wish you the best.